# django on dotcloud tutorial: 404 admin not found

Tags: django, dotcloud

I am a python/django newbie following along this [tutorial on dotcloud](http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django/). I git cloned the scripts, and did not change anything. After I do a dotcloud push, I get a 404 error, admin not found.

Looking for answers, I found [this from dotcloud answers](http://answers.dotcloud.com/question/11/django-404-errors), checked my wsgi.py and found nothing different from what I cloned from the tutorial. I also did a dotcloud logs -b mysite and found nothing wrong.

I also ran a

```
dotcloud run mysite python current/path_to/manage.py syncdb
```

and I still get

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://jims-now0pen.dotcloud.com/
    Using the URLconf defined in hellodjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
        ^admin/
    The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

What should I do to fix this? I appreciate your help --thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial application does not provide an URL mapping for the root URL (http://jims-now0pen.dotcloud.com/); however, you can go to http://jims-now0pen.dotcloud.com/admin/ to see Django's admin site.

This is explained at the end of [this paragraph](http://docs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/python/django/#django-admin-site):

> If we push our application now, we can go to the /admin URL [...]